# SQL query error on simple queries in Drupal website

Tags: mysql, drupal

We have a bunch of Drupal environments set up, and we send commands to them from a centralized server.  When sending commands from this server they are in this format -

`drusha -v -d @website sql-query 'show tables;'`

However, I get the error -

`ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`

When I go onto the actual database server and manually run the commands, it works fine.

I've tried switching quotations and removing them all together, along with removing the ; at the end, but I get the same error every time.  The database information that the website is using is correct.  Any other commands run on using this alias work fine (drush clear-cache, etc), so I don't think the problem is with the actual alias.

Does anyone have any ideas why this would be occurring?

EDIT - When passing in --database=databasename I get the following error -

`drusha -v -d @website sqlq -n "SHOW TABLES" --database=databasename`

```
exception 'Drush\Sql\SqlException' with message 'Unable to find a    [error]
matching SQL Class. Drush cannot find your database connection
details.' in
phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/commands/sql/sql.drush.inc:588
Stack trace:
#0 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/commands/sql/sql.drush.inc(426):
drush_sql_get_class(NULL)
#1 [internal function]: drush_sql_query('SHOW', 'TABLES')
#2 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/command.inc(366):
call_user_func_array('drush_sql_query', Array)
#3 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/command.inc(217):
_drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
#4 [internal function]: drush_command('SHOW', 'TABLES')
#5 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/command.inc(185):
call_user_func_array('drush_command', Array)
#6 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(67):
drush_dispatch(Array)
#7 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/preflight.inc(66):
Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#8 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/includes/startup.inc(325):
drush_main()
#9 phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/drush(114): drush_startup(Array)
#10 /usr/local/bin/drush(10): require('phar:///usr/loc...')
```

EDIT2 - After some more fiddling, I got it to work with show tables by enclosing everything inside of a single and then double quotes, and switching the command I ran.  Right now, this is my command -

```
ssh -q <webserverip> sudo -u apache /usr/local/bin/drush --root=/var/www/html/wwwroot/website/docroot/ sql-query "'UPDATE users SET mail='local@host' WHERE uid>1'"
```

The error I am currently getting is -

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@host WHERE uid>1' at line 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: Removing the quotes gives the same error, as well as something like this - `'show tables';`.  Which quote is it that you are talking about and where should it be moved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use double quotes without ; execute command in folder where is located settings.php

```
drush -v -d  sql-query "show tables"
```

For multisite drupal:

```
drush -v -d  sql-query "show tables" --database=websitedbname
```

or

```
drush -v -d  sql-query "show tables" --target=website
```

https://drushcommands.com/drush-7x/sql/sql-query/

Also , you can connect manually to your database (mysql or other) and make your request.

Comment: When trying it like that, I still get an error.  I just added it to the original question

Comment: you have to be in folder where is located settings.php and databasename is the key of array in settings.php

Comment: Still didnt work for me.  I updated the question with some more information and a different error from another method I tried.  Could you check that one out as well?

Comment: Hum.. Those commands works for me.. Why do you use `drusha` instead of `drush` ?